# Opening/reading Access database in Classic ASP?

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic, onselect

I'm trying to populate the contents of a web form with an Onchange header function (select * in database where ID="somevalue") but I don't know how to open the database whilst in the header function nor how to read into the resulting recordset for later dissection.

Can anybody help? (And yes, I know this is old technology, but it is the hand I am dealt).

Comment: Could you post some code please?  An onchange header function sounds like it might be client side JavaScript and Classic ASP is server side so the two shouldn't intefere.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify: When you say "an Onchange header function" are you talking about a JavaScript function associated with the `change` event of some element in the document?

Comment: Are you guys telling me that opening a file/database in the header isn't as easy as I thought?  How can I post the pertinent code  sections??

Comment: Opening a file/database anywhere in the document is easy. Providing an answer to your question "open the database whilst in the header function" is difficult when we can't see the header function. Posting the header function would help solve that.

Comment: No, we're saying that your question is unclear. Please [edit] it to explain what you are actually trying to accomplish. For example: "When the user clicks on a [...] I want to query a database [on the server?] and display the results as [...]."

Comment: Okay. I have information on the screen one of its elements is a select menu. When a user scrolls through its selections and chooses one I want the Onchange function to be called with that selection's value.  The select menu gets its contents,including the values, off the database and works well. Once that selection is made the Onchange header function is called where a variable is constructed of the form SELECT * FROM DBASE WHERE ID=12.  I want to open the database, execute the query retrieving the record, dissect that record into its various fields and then finally to display them on screen

Comment: How can I upload source?  can you access [link] http://www.NHTF.NET/resreg.asp ?

Comment: Is the problem that I'm trying to access my database (server-side) from my HTML-called-javascript (client-side)? And, if so, how do I interface them to accomplish what I want?

Comment: Is anyone still reading this thread?? Gord?? Craig??

Comment: I'm still trying to solve this problem. Is this an impossible task to solve? If it is possible can somebody post some example code (e.g. let's say with a remote server called "XYZ.com" and a database on it called "MyData.MDB")

Is this technology that I should forget trying to use? If so, what would you suggest?

Thank you.

Ross